# Angular Web App - async functions (Observables) not working properly in IoS device (safari and chrome browser)

Tags: ios, angular, mobile, observable

We have developed an angular web app working fine in laptop/desktop and Android devices. But in IOS (safari and chrome) it is not working properly.

Async function (like observable in our case) the callback functions are not able to update HTML.

We are getting API data, but certain things like the data we have subscribed are not changing in the template file. Spinner is not turning off after getting the API data.

**Summary**- While using observable the subscribed data is not updating in HTML templates.